# Collection of sets vs Indexed family in point set topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory

In general topology, it is very common to use open coverings and various other collections of sets. For instance, in the definition of [cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)) on Wikipedia. However, I found two ways of denoting these collections, one as $C :=\{ U_{\alpha}:a\in A \}$ or as $\{ U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$. To be pedantic, in the former case every subset of $C$ is unique by the definition sets, while the latter is really a function from $A$ to subsets of the space, so for instance $U_{1} =U_{2}$ appears twice.

This has never really bothered me before reading about some theorems about paracompact space. Specifically,

> (**Shrinking Lemma**) If $X$ is paracompact (assume $T_{2}$), $\{ U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in A}$ an open cover. Then there exists locally finite open cover $\{ V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in A}$ with $\overline{V_{\alpha}} \subset U_{\alpha}$. (where $V_{\alpha} =\emptyset$ is allowed).

> (**Existence of partition of unity**) Let $X$ be a paracompact space $\{ U_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in A}$ an open cover of $X$. Then exists a partition of 1 $\{ p_{\alpha}:X \to [0,1] \}_{\alpha\in A}$ with $\operatorname{supp} p_{\alpha} \in U_{\alpha}$. $\operatorname{supp} (f) := \overline{\{ x\in X|f(x) \neq 0 \}}$

> **(Definition of partition of unity)** A partition of unity on a space $X$ is a collection of continuous function $\{ p_{\alpha}: X \to [0,1]\}_{\alpha \in A}$ so that $(1)$ $\{ \operatorname{supp}p_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a locally finite cover of $X$. (2) $\sum_{\alpha\in A}p_{\alpha}(x) = 1$ $\forall x\in X$

I'm reading a professor's [notes](http://lerman.web.illinois.edu/535/f20/lec26.pdf) I found online. In the proof of shrinking lemma, I think $V_{\alpha}$ can be the same for different $\alpha$. I'm not exactly sure why the professor wrote $V_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset$ is allowed.

More confusingly in the existence of partition of unity, I think by construction using the shrinking lemma, we do not have a different $p_{\alpha}$ for each $U_{\alpha}$, that is the same function might be used twice. And in the proof I found $\sum_{\alpha \in A} p_{\alpha}(x) = 1$ to be ambiguous, if we really have $U_{\alpha_{1}} = U_{\alpha_{2}} = \dots U_{\alpha_{n}} =\dots$, I felt we are not summing up the same $p_{\alpha}$ multiple times.

> So my question is what exactly is the theorem statement for the existence of partition of unity? Also, how should we think and write these things so that it does not cause greater confusion when theorems build on top of each other,

Comment: Maybe we can assume $V_{\alpha}$ is pairwise disjoint in the shrinking lemma by taking some of them being the empty set. And that might make the partition of unity work as well, I have to think about it.

Comment: Hello. Can you say any more about what's bothering you? I think everything goes fine here if you allow repetitions. If $U_{\alpha_1} = U_{\alpha_2}$ that won't necessarily imply that $V_{\alpha_1} = V_{\alpha_2}$ or $p_{\alpha_1} = p_{\alpha_2}$. (In fact, in that case, the shrinking lemma could always just give you $V_{\alpha_2} = \emptyset$!) If you wanted to be really formal you can replace each indexed family $U_\alpha$, $V_\alpha$, $p_\alpha$ with a function that has domain $A$. (Also I think you mean $\subseteq$ rather than $\in$ in the first lemma).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think actually if you replace repetition by empty set it might work, but if you allow repetition of nonempty set, first you need to define local finiteness (which is simple), but then for the existence partition of unity proof (I linked), I think one might end up with summing up infinitely nonzero functions.

Comment: Also yeah the construction of the shrinking lemma seems to give pairwise disjoing $V_{\alpha}$. It's really tedious to think in all these details, maybe I should just replace repetitions with empty set? I'm wondering what's the intention when one write these indexed family notations in this context, do they mean to allow repetitions? When writing open cover I thought typically we don't allow repetitions on the other hand

Comment: $V_\alpha$ definitely aren't pairwise disjoint! That's often impossible - eg in connected spaces. My point is that I think you're worrying unnecessarily - I just don't see why you think the proof doesn't work if there is repetition. Having a set repeated twice isn't that much "worse" than having two sets that have a big overlap, right? Can you point to the first step in these proofs that you don't feel is justified?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Sorry I meant if there are replications, they are both empty sets. I understand now. Originally I was confused by the definition of locally finite, and I thought that locally finite means that after we remove all the replications (I thought covering means a collection thus sets are all distinct), there exists a neighborhood intersect finite sets. But really the definition is to an indexed family which allows replication.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen 
The problem with the former definition is that in the existence of partition of unity proof, if we ignore the details of the first proof, and just thought of $\{ \overline{V_{\alpha}} \}_{\alpha\in A}$ as locally finite (in the sense of after removing replications), $\phi(x) = \sum_{\alpha \in A} \phi_{\alpha}(x)$ may not longer be a finite sum. Anyway, thank you so much for the clarification! I think that makes more sense now.